# How to use property names in error messages with AJV errors

Tags: javascript, jsonschema, ajv

I am using ajv-errors with ajv v8 - According to [docs](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv-errors#using-property-names-in-error-messages) I should be able to use a pointer to reference the field name but my attempts are failing with errors such as: `Cannot access property/index 0 levels up, current level is 0`

Example schema:

```
{
  $schema: "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  type: "object",
  additionalProperties: false,
  properties: {
    name: { type: "string" }
  },
  required: ["name"],
  errorMessage: {
   required:  'Field ${0#} is so required'
  }
}
```

Any ideas? I could probably use an absolute pointer but am not sure what data this is actually referring to in order to create a path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0#` is a [relative json pointer](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/relative-json-pointer.html#rfc.section.5.1) for the current members name or array index.

`ajv-errors` bases this lookup on the `{ field: value }` data it is validating rather than somewhere in the schema.

So inside a property `errorMessage` you have access to an object 1 level up:

```
{
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    named: {
      type: "string",
      errorMessage: {
        type: 'Field ${0#} is so ${1}', // 'Field "named" is so {"named":2}'
      },
    },
  },
}
```

It appears for `required`, there is no field or value so no data to lookup.

```
const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    name: {
      type: "string",
    },
  },
  required: ["name"],
  errorMessage: {
    required: {
      name: 'Field "name" is so ${0}', // 'Field "name" is so {}'
    }
  },
}
```

You can add an explicit message for each field as above.

Comment: Dang. I was afraid of that.

Comment: @cyberwombat were you able to find solution how to reference it??

Comment: @Miel I gave up on that package sorry.

Comment: @cyberwombat It's okay, thanks for replying.

Comment: any other package?